Mass Conservation in Kinetic Theory
In chapter 9 (The Boltzmann Equation) of Schwabl's 2006 text 'Statistical Mechanics', the author has the following statement of conservation of mass,
$$ \frac{\partial n}{\partial t} + \nabla \mathrm{j} = 0 \tag{1} $$
where $n$ - the particle-number density - is given by
$$ n(\mathrm{x},t) := \int f d^3v, $$
and $\mathrm{j}$ is the momentum density, given by
$$ \mathrm{j} = n(\mathrm{x},t)\mathrm{u}(\mathrm{x,t}) := m\int \mathrm{v} f d^3 v. $$
Now, shouldn't (1) read as $\frac{\partial n}{\partial t} + \nabla \cdot \mathrm{j} = 0$ - ie shouldn't we have the $divergence$ of $\mathrm{j}$ instead of its $gradient$?

Correct - I would presume it's a typo.

@AtmosphericPrisonEscape I thought so too - just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something critical.
